# ORA-39002, ORA-39168 on IMPDP, Object path GRANT was not found

Tags: oracle, impdp

I'm trying to impdp a schema with just one table on it. The impdp parfile looks like this:

```
LOGFILE=scott_impdp.log
DUMPFILE=scott.dmp
SCHEMAS=scott
REMAP_SCHEMA=scott:scott2
REMAP_TABLESPACE=scott:scott2
EXCLUDE=grant
PARALLEL=8
CLUSTER=N
TRANSFORM=disable_archive_logging:Y
```

However, I'm getting these errors:

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39168: Object path GRANT was not found.
```

If I'm not mistaken, EXCLUDE=grant is valid syntax according to https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-DC7668E1-C846-48C5-A0D5-F4659EC119BB.htm#SUTIL911

From that link:
`Specifying EXCLUDE=GRANT excludes object grants on all object types and system privilege grants.`

Removing `EXCLUDE=grant` seems to work, but why would that break the impdp in the first place?

EDIT:
My expdp parfile looks like this:

```
LOGFILE=scott_expdp.log
DUMPFILE=scott.dmp
SCHEMAS=scott
PARALLEL=8
CLUSTER=N
COMPRESSION=ALL
FLASHBACK_TIME=systimestamp
REUSE_DUMPFILES=Y
EXCLUDE=statistics
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for your participation. Have you tried the obvious? `EXCLUDE=GRANT` (upper-case). And then a question about your syntax: Is your schema `scott` a synonym for an existing schema that you don't want to disclose? Or does that schema actually exist? If the schema exists, does that schema hold any objects? Check with `select owner, object_name, object_type, status from all_objects where owner = 'scott';` executing as sys or system.

Comment: @hot2use Yeah I've tried `EXCLUDE=GRANT`, unfortunately that didn't solve it. Yes, `scott` is a synonym for the actual schema I'm using. Right now the schema just holds one table. I ran the query and it came up with the one table that I have in the db currently.

Answer (score 1):

This happened because you specified `EXCLUDE=GRANT` on export as well.

This is expected behavior - according to Oracle.

The workaround is to not specify the same `EXCLUDE` in `expdp` and `impdp`.

See the below (with support access):

[DataPump Import (IMPDP) Fails With ORA-39168 (Doc ID 430702.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=430702.1)

I have just tested this on version 18c and 19c as well, in those newer versions it worked fine without any error.

Comment: I specified `EXCLUDE=statistics` in the expdp, so unfortunately I don't think this is the case. I updated the original question with my expdp parfile